# Detecting Angular page change

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working with a third-party website that uses Angular.
I need to perform some actions when the user logs into the customer page, that means whenever the user goes from the log-in page, to his logged area. (Both are on the same website and use Angular).
This used to work before, since the actions happen on page reload, but since we are in an SPA, the page reload does not happen when the page changes.

My code lives on the page, but is not "inside" the Angular application and I have never used Angular before, so I only have visible to me the elements of the webpage that are global.

One way to solve the problem is to monitor the URL of the current page and detect when it changes from: `https://somedomain/#/loginpage` to `https://somedomain/#/loggedArea` using the `window.location` object:

```js
var previousHash; //This will store the hash of the page we were in before


// Then we would have to constantly check if the URL has changed
if(previousHash == "#/login" && window.location.hash == "#/loggedArea"){
  callOnLoadActions()
}
```

but that seems a little brittle and hacky to me.

Is there an "official", or at least better way of listening to when the page gets updated?

Comment: Can you invert this and make the angular app call a function on the window when it logs in?

Comment: To execute code when you leave a page you can use `onDestroy` lifecycle, or `canDeactivate` guard. But why don't you just do you stuff before redirecting ?

Comment: OP said it is 3rd party app, so he might have no control over the inside code or simply don't want to touch

Comment: I suggest listening to events but that requires having control over the Angular application.

Comment: Yes, @ABOS is right. I have no control over the Angular code, unfortunately. My code is placed in the webpage after is rendered and lives there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of an external solution to angular, but maybe using window.onhashchange will work in this scenario for you.

```
function YouAreGoingPlaces() {
    alert("Welcome to " + location.hash)
}
window.onhashchange = YouAreGoingPlaces() {
   your custom actions here.
}
```

Comment: I did a quick test, and this seems to work just fine. Thank you very much (PS: I had no idea the onhashchange existed. Learn something new today)